# Problema con procedimiento almacenado en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL. Este procedimiento se activará con un *trigger* para insertar registros en otra base de datos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost`
PROCEDURE db_test.`PROC_DO_INSERT_INTO_CAT_DEPARTMENT`(
   IN `sSchemaName`        VARCHAR(25),
   IN `nDepartment_Id`     INT,
   IN `sDepartment_Name`   VARCHAR(75))
BEGIN
   DECLARE sTableName   VARCHAR(75);
   SET sTableName := concat(trim(sSchemaName), '.cat_department');
   INSERT INTO sTableName  //Linea que genera el error
      (department_id, department_name)
      VALUES
      (nDepartment_Id, sDepartment_Name);
END;
```

Al llamarlo desde el esquema `db_local`:

```
CALL `db_test`.`PROC_DO_INSERT_INTO_CAT_DEPARTMENT`('db_remote', 2, 'ADMINISTRACION');
```

Me tira el error *`db_local.sTableName` no existe*. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Claro, no puedes usar variables como nombre de tabla u otro objeto en una sentencia SQL, lo que te dice es que justamente la tabla `sTableName `  no existe. Eventualmente lo que podrías hacer es crear una sentencia dinámica y ejecutarla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambie el INSERT y deje el SP de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost`
PROCEDURE db_test.`PROC_DO_INSERT_INTO_CAT_DEPARTMENT`(
   IN `sSchemaName`        VARCHAR(25),
   IN `nDepartment_Id`     INT,
   IN `sDepartment_Name`   VARCHAR(75))
BEGIN
    Set @SqlStr = concat('insert into ', sTableName, ' (department_id, department_name) ',' values (', nDepartment_Id, ', ', sDepartment_Name,');');
    prepare Stmt from @SqlStr;
    Execute Stmt;
    Deallocate prepare Stmt;
END;
```

He trabajado muy poco con MySQL, por lo que ando un poco fuera de ritmo, pero de cualquier forma gracias por la ayuda.